# 'Circumference' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++14

I am taking an introductory course in C++ ver. 14 and I keep running into this error. Code is using header file and I'm not sure how to effectively transfer user numerical inputs from the `.cpp` file to the `.h` file and vice versa.  Here is my code for the `.cpp` file:

```
   #include<iostream>
  //ignore this part the stack overflow code editor 
  //is being weird here
   #include<string>

   #include "Circle.h"
 using namespace std;

int main()
{

//instantiate the Circle.h code 
Circle ObjData; //object to store information in

//user inputs radius value  
cout << "Please enter the initial radius: ";
cin >> ObjData.getRadiusVal();

//display the circle radius check
cout << "\nThis is the radius of the circle: " << RadiusVal << endl;

//display the rest of the circle calculations
//get the calculated variables from circle.h
    getCircleDiam() const;
{
    return CircleDiam
}

    getCircumference() const;
{
    return Circumference
}

    getCircleArea() const;
{
    return CircleArea
}


cout << "This is the diameter of the circle: " << ObjData.getCircleDiam() << endl;
cout << "This is the circumference of the circle: " << ObjData.getCircumference() << endl;
cout << "This is the area of the circle: " << ObjData.getCircleArea() << endl;

}
```

And here is the .h file:

```
 #include<string>
using namespace std;

class Circle
{

private:

double RadiusVal;

public:
//set functions
void setCircleDiam(double);
void setCircumference(double);
void setCircleArea(double);
//get functions
double getRadiusVal() const;
double getCircleDiam() const;
double getCircumference() const;
double getCircleArea() const;

};

//member function that retrieves the radius value from circletest.cpp
double Circle::getRadiusVal() const
{
    return RadiusVal;
}
    
//initialize the calculated variables
//double CircleDiam, Circumference, CircleArea;

//member function that calculates diameter
void setCircleDiam(double)
{
CircleDiam = RadiusVal*2;
}   
//member function that calculates circumference
void setCircumference(double)
{
Circumference = 2*3.14159*RadiusVal;
}
//member function that calculates circular area
    void setCircleArea(double)
    {
    CircleArea = 3.14159*RadiusVal^2;
    }
```

For some reason I keep getting this error message when trying to compile

In file included from CircleTest.cpp:11:0: Circle.h: In function 'void setCircleDiam(double)': Circle.h:42:2: error: 'CircleDiam' was not declared in this scope   CircleDiam = RadiusVal*2;   ^~~~~~~~~~ Circle.h:42:15: error: 'RadiusVal' was not declared in this scope   CircleDiam = RadiusVal*2;
^~~~~~~~~ Circle.h: In function 'void setCircumference(double)': Circle.h:47:2: error: 'Circumference' was not declared in this scope   Circumference = 2*3.14159*RadiusVal;   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ Circle.h:47:28: error: 'RadiusVal' was not declared in this scope   Circumference = 2*3.14159*RadiusVal;
^~~~~~~~~ Circle.h: In function 'void setCircleArea(double)': Circle.h:52:2: error: 'CircleArea' was not declared in this scope   CircleArea = 3.14159*RadiusVal^2;   ^~~~~~~~~~ Circle.h:52:23: error: 'RadiusVal' was not declared in this scope   CircleArea = 3.14159*RadiusVal^2;
^~~~~~~~~ CircleTest.cpp: In function 'int main()': CircleTest.cpp:33:17: error: 'getCircleDiam' was not declared in this scope    getCircleDiam() const;
^ CircleTest.cpp:36:2: error: expected ';' before '}' token   }   ^ CircleTest.cpp:38:20: error: 'getCircumference' was not declared in this scope    getCircumference() const;
^ CircleTest.cpp:41:2: error: expected ';' before '}' token   }   ^ CircleTest.cpp:43:17: error: 'getCircleArea' was not declared in this scope    getCircleArea() const;
^ CircleTest.cpp:46:2: error: expected ';' before '}' token   }   ^

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? What am I missing in defining these variables in both files? Are either of my files completely messed up in terms of overall code formatting?

Comment: Also, `setCircleDiam` in your `Circle.h` isn't actually a _member_ function. It lacks the `Circle::`

Comment: Wouldn't that make it unneccessary to have the .h file at all?

Comment: @AdAstraInfinitum check the answer below. The `.h` is not strictly necessary, but it can be more beneficial to have a `Circle` as a separate file so that you can reuse it anywhere else.

Comment: This is a complete mess -- look at some code examples of how class member functions should be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look toward the following implementation. Your header file should look somewhat like these:

```
#include <cmath>

class Circle {
    double RadiusVal;
    double CircleArea;
    double Circumference;
    double CircleDiam;
public:
    // Constructor
    // Both, the dafault constructor
    // and the one that takes a double.
    Circle(const double &r = 1.0) :
        RadiusVal(r),
        CircleArea(3.14159*pow(r,2)),
        Circumference(2*3.14159*r),
        CircleDiam(r*2) {}

    // Set functions
    // You can still implement these
    // But consider that now when you modify one value,
    // Other values should also change accordingly  
    void setCircleDiam(double);
    void setCircumference(double);
    void setCircleArea(double);

    //Get functions
    double getRadiusVal() const {return RadiusVal; }
    double getCircleDiam() const {return CircleDiam; }
    double getCircumference() const {return Circumference; }
    double getCircleArea() const {return CircleArea; }
};
```

The `.cpp` file should look somewhat like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Circle.h"

int main() {
    double rad;
    //user inputs radius value  
    std::cout << "Please enter the initial radius: ";
    std::cin >> rad;
    
    Circle c(rad); // all construction logic is internal to Circle class

    //display the circle radius check
    std::cout << "\nThis is the radius of the circle: " << c.getRadiusVal() << '\n';
    
    //display the rest of the circle calculations
    std::cout << "Radius: "  << c.getRadiusVal() << '\n'
    std::cout << "Diameter: "  << c.getCircleDiam()  << '\n'
    std::cout << "Circumference: "  << c.getCircumference()  << '\n'
    std::cout << "Area: "  << c.getCircleArea()  << '\n'
}
```

Example:

```
Please enter the initial radius: 1

This is the radius of the circle: 1
Radius: 1
Diameter: 2
Circumference: 6.28318
Area: 3.14159
```

Note the use of constructor, as opposed to "setter" methods,
is the correct way to **populate an object with initial values** (right into its data members). "Setter" methods should be used when we want to modify already (fully) instantiated object, not to populate an object with values gradually.

Comment: Thanks this has been extremely helpful!! I still need to run a few more tests with user input but I think that about solved the issues I was having! This was also really informative.

Comment: @AdAstraInfinitum yeah! You may want to check for valid input from the user, i.e. so that radius won't be negative and similar sane constraints.

Comment: @AdAstraInfinitum go for it :)

Comment: Hey I have one more quick question.
I modified the .h input to accept user defined like so:

Comment: double get_RadiusVal() const
 {
  return radii;
 }
 
 Circle(const double &RadiusVal) 
 {
 CircleDiam = RadiusVal*2;
 Circumference = 2*3.14159*RadiusVal;
 CircleArea = 3.14159*pow(RadiusVal,2);
 }

Comment: And it keeps giving me this error:
Local\Temp\cc5dSXtv.o:CircleTest.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `Circle::getRadiusVal() const'
Local\Temp\cc5dSXtv.o:CircleTest.cpp:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `Circle::getCircleDiam() const'
Local\Temp\cc5dSXtv.o:CircleTest.cpp:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `Circle::getCircumference() const'
Local\Temp\cc5dSXtv.o:CircleTest.cpp:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `Circle::getCircleArea() const'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What's going on here?

Comment: @AdAstraInfinitum you either did not included the `.h` here, or modified some names, or else. It;s hard to tell from this. I suggest you to follow the layout in the answer. Also, it you want to accept user input, it's better to be done not in `.h` file.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. Didn't see some semicolons I added by mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: @AdAstraInfinitum best of luck to you!

Comment: The constructor should initialize _all_ the data members.  It can have an empty body.

Comment: @TobySpeight that's for sure!

Comment: @TobySpeight totally missed that. Thanks!